# chrome.storage.session availability/docs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I found several threads suggesting that `chrome.storage.session` API, one that should allow MV3 extensions to store sensitive data in-memory across service worker restarts, should already be available (e.g. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1185226 or https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/18V6_-5Hwbw) but I struggle to find any docs/examples on how to use it. I even tried searching on github without luck. Is the `chrome.storage.session` API actually available in a stable version of Chrome? If so, can you point me at some relevant resources/examples?

Comment: Regarding official docs, it has been reported as an issue: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com/issues/1851

Comment: btw, I just managed to access the `chrome.storage.session` object in my MV3 extension and actually store/retrieve some objects there, but without docs explaining the expected behavior/interface and type coverage (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/59704) it's a bit of a hit-or-miss :(

Comment: It has the same API surface as chrome.storage.local, but limited to 1MB overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation for the chrome.storage.session API is now available

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#property-session